# C++ array cin loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to learn C++,  I'm a newbie.
I have a small array program my teacher is having me write.
He wants multiple arrays with a menu to choose which one you want.
My only problem is I have problems in a few for loops.
Option one and two get me their but i looks like cin doesn't work right or something.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Array1[5];
    int Array2[2];
    int Array3[4];
    int choice1;
    int choice2;


    cout << "******************************************" << endl;
    cout << "*  this damn thing has killed me today   *" << endl;
    cout << "******************************************\n\n\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "    Here is some options  \n\n" << endl;
    cout << "      1) start array of 5\n " << endl;
    cout << "      2) Make another array. Choices are  2/4" << endl;
    cout << "      3) Exit" << endl;
    cin >> choice1;

    if (choice1 == 1)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
        {
            cout << "Lets start this" << endl;
            int y = 0;
            int n = 0;

            int x;
            cin >> x;
            Array1[a] = x;

            cout << " Wann see the numbers you entered??  Y/N" << endl;
            int question;
            cin >> question;
            if (question == y)
            {
                cout << Array1[0];
                cout << Array1[1];
                cout << Array1[2];
                cout << Array1[3];
                cout << Array1[4];
                cout << "n\n\\n" << endl;
                cout << "Bye Bye" << endl;
            }
            else if (question == n)
            {
                cout << "\n\n Bye Bye" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (choice1 == 2)
    {
        cout << "Which Array Shall We DO??????\n1)2?\n2)4?\n" << endl;
        cin >> choice2;
        if (choice2 == 1)
            for (int c = 0; c < 2; ++c)
            {
                int z = 0;
                Array2[c] = z;
                cin >> z;

                cout << "Would you like to see the Array of 2? y/n?  " << endl;
                int q1;
                int y = 0;
                int n = 0;
                cin >> q1;

                if (q1 == y)
                {
                    cout << Array2[0];
                    cout << Array2[1];

                    cout << "\n\n\nBye Bye" << endl;
                    return 0;
                }

                if (q1 = n)
                {
                    cout << "\n\nBye Bye" << endl;
                }

            }
        if (choice2 = 2)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < 4; ++d)
            {
                int y = 0;
                int n = 0;
                int w = 0;
                int q2;
                Array3[d] = w;
                cout << "Enter Numbers........\n\n" << endl;
                cin >> w;

                cout << "Would You Like to See Array?????    y/m\n\n" << endl;
                cin >> q2;

                if (q2 == y)
                {
                    cout << Array3[0];
                    cout << Array3[1];
                    cout << Array3[2];
                    cout << Array3[3];
                }

                if (q2 == n)
                {
                    cout << "\n\n\nBye Bye! " << endl;
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if (choice1 == 3)
    {
        cout << "Bye Bye" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First I fixed your indentation as it made your code hard to read.  Secondly It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You should always include the errors you are getting when asking questions. Not just the code. The errors help us figure out what is wrong.

Comment: `if (choice2 = 2)` .. will always be true. you seem to have phatphingered the second `=` in what I can only assume should have been `==`. Same goes for `if (q1 = n)`. Jam up your compiler warnings to max levels. Most reasonable compilers would flag both of those.

Comment: i have no error now. work those out,
one thing the compiler doesnt pick up is the for loops.

Comment: should be input for the arrays then out put the arrays but what i get is

    Here is some options


      1) start array of 5

      2) Make another array. Choices are  2/4
      3) Exit
1
Lets start this
1
heres what your array is
1-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460n
\n
Bye Bye
Lets start this

compiler shows no error

Comment: @MichaelDarnell you do have errors. Your loops repeat, you get weird numbers, you have a few spelling mistakes, and your program quits when the user answers when you say you don't want to see the numbers. These are all errors. It isn't just when the compiler spits out errors at you. All these errors are hints as to where your program is going wrong. I hope my answer below helps you and makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off there are quite a few errors here. Since you're new to programming, I want to help you with the process. I don't want to do your homework, but I am going to give you enough information to get it done very quickly.

Has your teacher introduced you to the switch statement? If so, this is a great time to use it. Anyway, we'll stay in scope here.

So let's look at the code in sections

```
 if (choice1 == 1)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
    {
        cout << "Lets start this" << endl;
        int y = 0;
        int n = 0;

        int x;
        cin >> x;
        Array1[a] = x;
```

What is happening here? First off I want to let you know that this outputs to the user

```
Lets start this
```

The user is probably confused, as are you. But I get that you want a number and so we type 2.

The next part

```
cout << " Wann see the numbers you entered??  Y/N" << endl;
            int question;
            cin >> question;
            if (question == y)
```

There are three problems I see here.
First, I'll ask you what type is the letter Y? Its a character. Not an integer. Second, what happens if your user types a lower case y? You should also work on your questions to the user. Remember, the user is dumb and doesn't know what you're doing. Third, try `if (question == 'y')`

So now after we fixed this let's recompile and see what happens? We don't get that break anymore, but we're suddenly trapped in a loop. Also we print weird numbers. So why is this? Let's change line 8 to `int Array1[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};` Why am I doing this? See if you notice the pattern in what is happening when you print your statements. There is an easy fix, but this is formatting and style.

The last problem you have is with your else statement. Why are you using else if? Why not else? And why return 0? Do you want the user to quit the program if they answer no? Comment this whole section out and see what happens.

Your other problems are similar to these described above. There are three things I will highly suggest.

1) Write pseudo code. I know it is a pain and annoying, but it doesn't take long and saves you hours of debugging. It would have solved your problems here.

2) Make sure that the questions you are asking your user is are clear.

3) Your users are dumb, and your teacher will probably act dumb when testing your code on purpose. Ask questions like "What if the user responds with something I didn't account for? Like placing a number where a character should be. That's what if then else if then else statements are good for. Be sure to use OR statements (||) to account for capital and lower cases. If you want to be really good figure out how to pass a 'y' for an input of 'Y' or 'Yes' or 'yes'.

I hope this all helps. the code compiles and runs fine after these fixes on my side. If this doesn't answer it all I'll drop more hints.

Comment: Oh and one more thing. COMMENT COMMENT COMMENT. Your teacher and/or TA will love you to death if you comment the heck out of your code. And future you will as well. Get in the habit now.

Comment: thank you. i kept forgetting this and that. i change it up. and i have it all fixed  thank you.

Comment: Good to know. Remember to always take things in steps. It will make your life a lot easier.